# How to send data from iPhone to a Server and show it in the site

Tags: php, ios, iphone, json, heroku

What I've learned and things that I'm not sure about if I need:

- A server like one of heroku provided.
- A database to handle what I will send.
- Something written for backend and mostly its written in php.
- To send data from iPhone to server with `NSData` and `NSUrl` with json .
- To receive what I sent from iPhone and handle it.

But I don't even know where to write PHP files to deploy on sites or anything about database creation.

Comment: You know what you need to do, you should go out and attempt it. Look at: [Create a JSON RESTfull API using Slim framework](https://coderwall.com/p/otcphg) that you'd send the data to and process for storing in the database. The only way you're going to learn properly is from trial and error!

Comment: @Darren i don't know where to start.That's the problem

Comment: I've supplied some information for you to get started there. You can also check out [**`PDO Prepared Statements`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for inserting the data into tables securely (*well preventing sql injections*).

Answer (score 0):

This are some Tutorials that helps you.

1 [Using PHP’s JSON encode and decode functions to handle data sent to and from your app](http://samcroft.co.uk/2014/php-json-encode-decode-functions-tutorial/)

2 [JSON Over HTTP On The iPhone](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

At first start developing the web service .To start with a local server Use any webserver like XAMP,LAMP,tomcat,ect.

1. create a database using the phpMyadmin from your browser and also a user name to use by your application.
2. Use the URL like localhost/home/../api.php to get the api which interacts to our application.it depends on the server you use and you can get it [XAMP](http://www.udemy.com/blog/xampp-tutorial/),[LAMP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)
3. Use php to code the api and for making the output in json, you can use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).
4. in Your iOS app, use a method to post the request, such as [NSMutableURLRequest](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/) with required parameters.
5. To make a  request in json format you can use

   NSString *jsonRequest = [jsonDict JSONRepresentation];

   This should be placed in the body of the post request. You can also use normal post
   request with parameters. I depends on how you process your request at the api.
6. To get the response from api, implement NSURLConnectionDataDelegate ,
   NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods.
7. To get the json object from response

   json=[NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                   error:&error];

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please expand on it more.

Comment: @user3819540 hope this will help. Enjoy the coding.